# How do I write javascript cookies from a form and then print the info in an alert or hidden div?

Tags: javascript, cookies, forms

How do I use JavaScript to write cookies from form fields, and then print the info in an alert or hidden div?

Here is an example of what I have tried thus far.....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cookieForm() {
 document.cookie = "name_first" + encodeURIComponent(document.forms[0].name_first.value); 
}
function printCustomerInfo() {
 var queryData = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
 var queryArray = queryData.split(";");
if (document.cookie) {
   window.alert("Your info. is:" + queryArray[0]);
   window.alert[0].name_last.value = QueryArray[1].substring(queryArray[1].lastIndexOf("=") + 1);
}
}
</script>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="cookieForm(), printCustomerInfo()"/>
```

Comment: As this is, I receive a message that name_first=undefined. I'm new at this and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're missing the "=" in the cookie string:

```
document.cookie = "name_first=" + encodeURIComponent(document.forms[0].name_first.value);
```

Second, your queryData has no ";" to split by, and no last name value - at least from what you show here.

This I do not understand:

```
window.alert[0].name_last.value = ...
```

I would call a single function from your event, and let that parent both setting the cookie and parsing it.  That way you can at least debug it better.

re: a div, you could do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("yourDiv").innerHTML = "Your info. is:" + queryArray[0];
document.getElementById("yourDiv").style.visibility = 'visible';
```

But in general it's better to use jquery for manipulating elements, because it mitigates browser differences, though it wouldn't matter in this case:

```
$("yourDiv").html("Your info. is:" + queryArray[0]);
$("yourDiv").css ( { 'visibility': 'visible' } );
```

Good luck.

Comment: I added the "=" and it is finally writing the cookies - thank you! The last name was just the rest of the information I am working with (I omitted it for the example's sake). I got the "window.alert[0].name_first.value = " statement from my book. I have changed it to one window alert that prints multiple 'queryArray[]' values, and it seems to be working, but with terrible display. do you know how I would print this to a popup div instead?